# Update variable value in XSLT for-each loop

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML:

```
<Root>
  <Employee>
    <Name>Dash</Name>
    <Age>23</Age>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <Name>Gwen</Name>
    <Age>22</Age>
  </Employee>
</Root>
```

And I need to convert to below XML using XSLT:

```
<Root>
  <Employee>
    <Name>Dash,Gwen</Name>
    <Age>23,22</Age>
  </Employee>
</Root>
```

I am using the for-each loop to get the values of the sub-nodes of the `<Employee>` node.The problem I am facing is I cannot figure out how to store the concatenated values in another temperoary variable in XSLT.I found on many sites that we cannot update the variables in the XSLT, so is there any alternative solution for this?

Comment: Why is necessary to to store the concatenated values in a temporary variable?

Comment: you need to use a recursive template or try to come up with a solution that does not need the temporary variable.

Comment: @Pawel Why would you need to use a recursive template?

Comment: @michael.hor257k - recursive templates allow to emulate loops with temp variables by passing a new variable value to the next reursive call.

Comment: @Pawel I know what recursive templates do. Why would you need to use one **here**?

Comment: Yes @Pawel can you please explain how to use recursive template in my case?

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0, or are you limited to XSLT 1.0?

Comment: @TimC I can use XSLT 2.0

Comment: In that case, the answer provided by Chong Lip Phang will work for you (It works in XSLT 2.0 as well as XSLT 3.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I meant by "*use a common template for both and avoid the code repetition*":

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <Root>
        <Employee>
            <Name>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Employee/Name"/>
            </Name>
            <Age>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Employee/Age"/>
            </Age>
        </Employee>
    </Root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Name|Age">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

While I am here, let me also point out that this replaces a solid XML structure with a very problematic one. I am not sure what's the purpose of this transformation, but the result is an XML that could be very difficult to consume by downstream applications.

Comment: Nice optimization @michael.hor257k. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Will this do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="Root">
      <Root>
         <Employee>
            <Name>
              <xsl:value-of select="Employee/Name" separator="," />
            </Name>
            <Age>
              <xsl:value-of select="Employee/Age" separator="," />
            </Age>
         </Employee>
      </Root>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Note to anyone trying this: it requires an XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 processor. With a 1.0 processor, the separator attribute will be ignored, and only the first Employee/Name or Employee/Age will be output.

Comment: @Chong Lip Phang:- When I use your code, It gives an error separator attribute is not declared.

Comment: @Dash Are you sure you are using an XSLT 2.0 processor? Which one? And what is the **exact** error message you're getting?

Comment: No its not XSLT 2.0 processor. I am sorry for that. And I guess the error is due to this reason only!!

Comment: @Dash In such case, Joel's answer will probably work for you, albeit a little inefficiently due to the repeated code. Unless you have some special requirement (you never answered my question about why it's necessary to store the concatenated values in a temporary variable).

Comment: It is not necessary now @michael.hor257k.It was thinking about using a temporary variable to store the value of the first Name node and append the value successive Name nodes to that temporary variable and at the end of the process using the value of temp vaiable

Answer (score 0):

please try the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Root">
        <Root>
            <Employee>
                <Name>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Employee/Name">
                        <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
                            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Name>
                <Age>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Employee/Age">
                        <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
                            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Age>
            </Employee>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or as an alternative,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Root>
            <Employee>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Root/Employee[1]"/>
            </Employee>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Employee[1]/Name|Employee[1]/Age">
        <xsl:variable name="curr_name" select="name()"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each select="following::*[name()=$curr_name]">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Couldn't you use a common template for both and avoid the code repetition?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have created an alternative stylesheet. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: No, not quite - see my answer.